# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ListFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `TabsPagerAdapter` class as below. The classes FirstFragment, SecondFragment and ThirdFragment each extended `Fragment` and all was well.
Then I changed SecondFragment to extend `ListFragment` and now I get  compile error:
*Type mismatch: cannot convert from SecondFragment to Fragment*

`ListFragment` extends `Fragment`, so in my mind. this shouldn't be a problem.
What do I do?

Import in SecondFragment is:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

Class:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        Fragment returnFragment = null;

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            returnFragment = new FirstFragment(mContext);
            break;
        case 1:
            returnFragment=  new SecondFragment(mContext);
            break;
        case 2:
            returnFragment = new ThirdFragment(mContext);
            break;
        }

        return returnFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the imports. Probably you imported the wrong ListFragment. Also fragments should have only the empty constructor

Comment: Added more info to clarify the ListFragment class

Comment: check which Fragment did you import in `TabsPagerAdapter` now

Comment: That's it. It is a  ...support.v4 .... So post an answer to the effect of check for the correct class of Fragment (support or not) and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is usually due of a  mismatch between the import in the different classes. You probably have the native `Fragment` in one class and the one from the support library in the other. Fix the imports and it will work. 
check the imports. Also remove the constructor that takes a parameter in  your `Fragment` subclasses. The system wants a public empty constructor (aka default constructor). If you need a context, you can use `getActivity()`