# cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I created a `FragmentOne extends Fragment`, and I am getting the following compile-time error:

> "cannot be converted to Fragment!",

I am following this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
  public void selectFrag(View view){
      Fragment fragment;
      if(view == findViewById(R.id.button1)){
          fragment = new FragmentOne();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the import . If you are using support fragment for FragmentTransaction then use the v4 format of the fragment

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656822/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-listfragment-to-fragment) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using AppcompatActivity . so replace your fragment imports to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: thanks,the converted problem is solved,but a new problem "FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();",required "v4.app.FragmentManager",found"app.FragmentManager"

Comment: If my answer helped you to resolve your problem.then please don't forget to mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: You may add another question with your new problem.

Comment: please change the imports in your fragment classes also

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is the Fragment class in the android support library, which is a compatibility package that allows you to use some of the newer features of Android on older versions of Android.

android.app.Fragment is the Fragment class in the native version of the Android SDK. It was introduced in Android 3 (API 11).

If you want to make your app use fragments, and want to target devices before API 11, you must use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use `android.app.Fragment`.